# How to correctly unfold a pack in order to create N element array

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, fold-expression

I was expecting this code to create 10 elements vector each constructed as `A{1, 2, 3.0}`, but in reality the output is `1`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    int a{0};
    int b{0};
    double c{0.0};
};

template<typename T, size_t... Ns>
auto create_array(std::index_sequence<Ns...>, auto&&... args) {
    return std::vector<T> {
        ([&](...){ return std::forward<T>(T{args...}); }(Ns), ...)
    };
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
auto create_array(auto&&... args) {
    return create_array<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << create_array<A, 10>(1,2,3.0).size() << std::endl;
}
```

How could this happen, why did not it unfold correctly? What is wrong here?
In particular I wanted this line

```
([&](...){ return std::forward<T>(T{args...}); }(Ns), ...)
```

to become

```
[&](...){ return std::forward<T>(T{args...}); }(0),
[&](...){ return std::forward<T>(T{args...}); }(1),
[&](...){ return std::forward<T>(T{args...}); }(2),
//...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you mention:

```
([&](...){ return std::forward<T>(T{args...}); }(Ns), ...)
```

is a fold expression. It only returns the last value because that's how the comma operator works. Remove the parentheses and the comma to instead expand the expression with `Ns` into an initializer list:

```
template<typename T, size_t... Ns>
auto create_array(std::index_sequence<Ns...>, auto&&... args) {
    return std::vector<T> {
        [&](...){ return std::forward<T>(T{args...}); }(Ns)...
    };
}
```

Comment: The `forward`ing is pointless as currently used.

Comment: yesh, it is actually r-value all the time in that case anyway and copy-elision should work. I just forgot to remove it for my example

Answer (score 5):

This

```
return std::vector<T> {
    ([&](...){ return std::forward<T>(T{args...}); }(Ns), ...)
};
```

Unpacks to

```
return std::vector<T> {
    ([&](...){ return std::forward<T>(T{args...}); }(0),
     [&](...){ return std::forward<T>(T{args...}); }(1),
     [&](...){ return std::forward<T>(T{args...}); }(2),
     /* etc */)
};
```

Which is a parenthesized chain of comma operators, which evaluates to the last expression in sequence. You want to simply unpack into the vectors arguments, without the fold expression:

```
return std::vector<T> {
    [&](...){ return std::forward<T>(T{args...}); }(Ns)...
};
```

Comment: The `forward`ing is pointless as currently used.

Answer (score 0):

I see four issues:

- The fold over the comma operator discards all but the last instance, so you only get one. You need to do a pack expansion instead.
- Using `auto&&...` as a parameter declaration is not valid C++17.
- The use of `std::forward` is pointless. If left in the code, someone might feel tempted to later change it into

  ```cpp
  return T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
  ```

  which could make the first instantiated `T` leave `args...` in a valid, but indeterminate state. `std::string`s could be emptied etc. Just remove `std::forward`.
- You are creating a `std::vector<T>` instead of a `std::array<T, N>`.

Corrected:

```cpp
template <class T, size_t... Ns, class... Args>
constexpr auto create_array(std::index_sequence<Ns...>, Args&&... args) {
    return std::array{
        [&](std::size_t) { return T{args...}; }(Ns)...
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem might be more complicated, but in this particular case you could simply use a constructor that takes a number of elements as a parameter:

```
template<typename T, size_t N, class... Args>
auto create_array(Args&&... args) {
    return std::vector<T>(N, T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
}
```

Comment: Yes, I put `vector` just for simplicity, in reality I'd like to be able to create a `constexpr std::array<T, N>`, where `T` doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: @Dmitry This will work even if if `T` doesn't have a default constructor - but it won't work if `T` isn't copyable.